# Rename tag [parse] to [parse-server]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The [parse](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/parse) tag refers to Parse Server and I suggest to rename it to `parse-server` to

- make the tag consistent with the [parse-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-server) tag on StackOverflow
- prevent using the tag for `parsing` related questions by mistake